# How to fuse the handle of a magnifying glass to its body?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm trying to connect these two objects as smoothly and seamlessly as possible. I've merged vertices by distance and you can see the result in my screenshots. But when I add the subD modifier, these weird artifacts appear. I thought the quads and matching vertex numbers would get me a nice result but it's not even close. I think it might have something to do with those poles. Can anyone help with this please?

[image: here's the wireframe for close inspection]

Blend file:
[drive.google.com/file/d/1quXHsNqIvdCpclZDH_kQv4bVmy8RkV9g](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1quXHsNqIvdCpclZDH_kQv4bVmy8RkV9g/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file?

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Here it is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1quXHsNqIvdCpclZDH_kQv4bVmy8RkV9g/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: You have inner faces, remove them, also you have a Bevel modifier in Weight mode, make sure that it bevels the edges you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have these 4 inner faces that create a bad shading, remove them. Also you have given a *Bevel* modifier in *Weight* mode to your object, make sure that it bevels the desired edges.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help.
Thanks for helping the novice that is me!